# ActiveMQ messages are not being consumed

Tags: activemq-classic

We have a system where we integrated our ESB programs with ActiveMQ. From past some time we observed messages are not getting consumed & nothing gets logged into ESB log & also dequeue counts are not increasing in the ActiveMQ console.

Now when we click on the queue inside the ActiveMQ web console suddenly all messages start getting dequeue. This behaviour we observed so many times, but not understanding how ActiveMQ console triggers this dequeue.

In ActiveMQ log file only seeing following warning:

```
2021-08-12 02:40:37,448 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://17X.X.X.X:6666 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///172.x.x.x:6666@61616
```

Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is so bizarre I'm not sure where to start. Viewing the queue from the web console should really have *no impact* on the consumption of messages in any way. I have no idea how that would even be technically possible. Is this something you can reproduce reliably? If so, can you put together a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The EOFException often means client socket is disconnecting without the protocol close packet being received. Generally, it is an indication of a mis-coded client. Please share your ActiveMQ version, config and consumer code.